# Table columns adjustment (pivot)

Tags: python, pandas

new to programming,

I need to reajust my table:

```
     group  month1  month2  month3  month4
0        1     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1        1     0.0     0.0     2.0     3.0
2        1     0.0     0.0     2.0     2.0
3        1     0.0     0.0     2.0     0.0
4        1     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

To something like this:

```
     group  month     value
0        1     month1     NaN     
1        1     month1     0.0     
2        2     month2     2.0     
3        2     month2     3.0
4        2     month3     NaN
...
```

Is there any simple way to do so?

I tried to use cycle methods, but it seems to be kinda complicated.
thanks in advance )